# Update boolean column using 't' 'f' representation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, casting

I'm trying to update dynamically some columns using this query as example:

```
UPDATE db.user_channel AS y 
set is_favourite = x.is_favourite 
FROM (VALUES ('5378f031-7c93-4557-9ea7-8a8f047c7caa', 't')) as x(id,is_favourite) 
where x.id = y.id::text
```

The column is_favourite is of type boolean, and even though 't' and 'f' are valid boolean representations in PostgreSQL, I'm getting this casting complaints:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "is_favourite" is of type boolean but expression is of type text
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 48
```

Why is that? Thank you!

Comment: Use `true` instead  of `'t'`

Comment: I can't. I'm trying to create a generic query to update dynamically multiple columns/rows using this tool https://github.com/datalanche/node-pg-format, which parses all booleans to either 't' or 'f'

Comment: Then it's a bug in that tool. It should generate valid literals for each data type

Comment: Hmm indeed! I believe it's related to this one https://github.com/datalanche/node-pg-format/issues/9. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
set is_favourite = ( x.is_favourite = 't' )
```

There is a difference between Postgres parsing `'t'` in a SQL statement and interpreting as "true" versus reading the value from a column.